# How to rotate image continuously using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, rotation, image-rotation

I have a jquery code for image rotation. The problem is, it only rotates once. How can i make the rotation continues every time the button is clicked. The image is automatically inserted in a div when the user upload image or multiple images.

```
 $(".img-button").find(".img-rotate").click(function(){
        $(this).parent(".img-button").siblings(".upload-img").css({'transform': 'rotate(-90deg)'});
    });
```

Comment: Kindly accept a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery `data()` method

- `+ 90` clockwise
- `- 90` anticlockwise

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let angle = +$('img').data('angle') + 90; // clockwise
  $('img')
    .css({'transform': `rotate(${angle}deg)`})
    .data('angle', angle)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" data-angle="0">

<button>Rotate</button>
```

**For infinite rotation**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('img').addClass('infinte-rotation');
});
```

```css
.infinte-rotation {
  -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" data-angle="0">

<button>Rotate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try css and jquery combination to implement the effect.

```
<div><img class="image" src="your image source" alt="" /></div>

 .rotate-img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

then add the following code to trigger the button onclick

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".image").toggleClass("rotate-img");
  });
});
```